# I am not sure how to find set of linearly independent path in control flow graph

Tags: algorithm, control-flow-graph

Hi I am facing problem with finding set of linearly independent path.
Here is my set :

- **one**:0 1 3 7 8 3 2 4 6 10
- **two**: 0 1 3 7 9 3 2 5 6 10
- **three**: 0 1 3 2 4 5 6 10
- **four**: 0 1 2 4 6 10
- **five**: 0 1 2 4 5 10

Is this linearly independent?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Linearly independent path are

```
1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 10

1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 6 -> 10
```

Mathematically

```
V(G) = E - N + 2
E= 13, N = 11, V(G) = 2
```

A path is independent, if it has non recurring nodes.
The two paths have non recurring nodes, whilst the the other paths have nodes recurring in them, such as node 3 and also some of the paths are never ending, as they are looping back again and again.